# How to find model no. in an image generated by OCR?

Tags: python, ocr

(Examples are changed but the idea is the same)

I'm trying find a SRD Model No. on a product label from a live camera feed.

Here's a label example:

[image]

The conditions are:

1. Different generations of the product have different structures of the information on the label.
2. The SRD Model No. has a variable length, varies from generation to generation.
3. The SRD Model No. can contain ither only numbers or numbers and letters, varies from generation to generation.

So the question is, is there a way to find a substring of a SRD Model No. in a string generated from OCR, other then hard coding all possible variations?

Comment: I do not see any SRN number in the example image. Are you referring to the SRD instead? Are these the same thing? Is it safe to assume that the number you are looking for will always be preceded by the "SRD" characters?

Comment: what did you do so far? what's the actual problem?

Comment: @Sheldon, yes, I meant SRD, sorry. And no, different generations describe it differently.

Comment: @raphael, I got a live feed from the camera and every few frames it checks for text and generates a string if found. Then I started to think how to extract the model number from generated string, but i couldn't think of solution other then hard coding every combination of possible variations. I need to create a list of model numbers, so I'm trying to create a script with which I can just point camera at a label and it auto populates a spreadsheet.

Comment: presumably there are only a few "generations" you need to deal with?  if so, it might be worth just performing feature matching from some library of known layouts. then OCR the area that you calculate based on the best matched set of features

Comment: @SamMason, right now there are 13 of the once that I know. Plus, since the company likes to edit it so much, I'd like to make it forward compatible.

Comment: I'd suggest building a library if it's only 13.  specifically "OCR only" approaches can be fragile in non-obvious ways.  for example, if the value is below the text rather than beside it (as all posts have been assuming) which a human would figure out based on table lines, but OCR would likely ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example script following @Angus Comber's suggestion:

```
import pytesseract
import numpy as np
import cv2
from cv2 import imread, cvtColor, COLOR_BGR2HSV as HSV, inRange, getStructuringElement, resize

from pytesseract import image_to_data, Output

def extract_SRD(filename):     
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    img_copy = img.copy()
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3,3),0)

    mydata = pytesseract.image_to_data(img_blur, output_type=Output.DICT, config='--psm 6')
    SRD = mydata['text'][mydata['text'].index('SRD')+2]

    return SRD

filename = 'wm3tG.png'

SRD  = extract_SRD(filename)

print(SRD)
```

This snippet returns:
**5427G2**

The important line here is `SRD = mydata['text'][mydata['text'].index('SRD')+2]`. This is where you define the logic used to retrieve the SRD code. In this example, I simply query the second string of characters after SRD, thus skipping the word "Model".

I would suggest fine-tuning this example to check whether a specific value in the output dictionary *contains* "SRD". Then you may simply look for the next string of characters:

- if this next string contains "Model", then return the one after that
- if not return that string of characters.

Comment: I suspect that installing Tesseract under a Google Colab notebook is not the same as installing it on a local workstation. You may want to check this medium article covering this topic in more detail: https://bhadreshpsavani.medium.com/how-to-use-tesseract-library-for-ocr-in-google-colab-notebook-5da5470e4fe0

Comment: @Sheldon, and as someone mentioned here, if there are variations of SRD prefix (like S/RD or Software RD), I can just create a dict to loop through, right?

Comment: Yes, this seems like the right way to proceed.

Comment: What is the advantage of img_blur using Gaussian? It seems the last 2 lines of code in the function return the expected result.

Comment: Good question @Mario. I agree that this step is not needed when dealing with a clean input image like the one provided in the question, but it may prove useful when working with "real world examples" (@art.less.code mentions labels read from a "live camera feed").  In this situation, Gaussian blurring may help remove gaussian noise from the input image.

Answer (score 0):

Use OCR to capture the product label to text. Search for the string SRD Model: then grab text 1 char after space to next whitespace and that is your SRD number.

Comment: There are quite a few different generations of the product and they have different descriptions. For example "SRD Model:", "SRD Model", "SRD_Model", "SRDM", or no legend at all, just information separated by new line.

Comment: If there is a list of known 'tags then you can iterate over them searching for each element. But if SRD can be placed in some random l9cation then that will definitely be tricky to automate.